# Rename [google-sql-cloud] to [google-cloud-sql]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

The proper name of the product is [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) but the tag name is currently [google-sql-cloud](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sql-cloud) (wrong) rather than [google-cloud-sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-sql) (correct).

Could you please rename the tag to fix the word order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[google-sql-cloud](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sql-cloud) merged into new tag [google-cloud-sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-sql) and a synonym created.